# What does the "kern" flag do in Linux net.h proto_ops accept

Tags: linux, sockets, kernel

In linux/net.h for Linux 4.18:

```
int     (*accept)    (struct socket *sock,
      struct socket *newsock, int flags, bool kern);
```

This function is used in kernel-space TCP servers like [this one](https://github.com/llj098/rcfile/blob/master/.vimbackup/tcp_svr_sample.c~). However, that example does not supply a value for the `kern` flag. (What is the advantage of Linux not being backward compatible with itself?)

Is this function documented?
How can we figure out what `kern` means?

**Update - A possible hint?**

I stumbled on the following while looking for something else:

http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1703.1/00970.html

> (3) Add a 'kern' parameter to ->accept() that is analogous to the one
>   passed in to ->create() that distinguishes whether kernel_accept() or
>   sys_accept4() was the caller and can be passed to sk_alloc().

In what world does "distinguishing the caller" explain a function's semantics? Anyways, this doesn't seem to answer the question, but could be a hint.

Comment: `kern` is probably a new parameter, and you have to provide a certain flag to use it. Older calls that omit the argument also won't set the corresponding flag.

Comment: @Barmar How would older calls compile, if the function prototype has changed?

Comment: You'll get a warning about the mismatched prototype, but it will still compile. As long as the function doesn't try to access the argument that wasn't supplied, nothing bad will happen.

Comment: @Barmar. That makes sense. OK, so the flag should be set to false. Can we also conclude that the Linux 4.18 kernel is completely undocumented?

Comment: `flags` is presumably a bit mask, not boolean. I'm not a kernel developer, but I think the "documentation" is mainly comments in the code.

Comment: @Barmar The flag I'm asking about is the `bool kern`, which does seem to be boolean. No, the code doesn't have useful comments around proto_ops.

Comment: Sorry, thought you were talking about the `flags` parameter.

Comment: Googling "Linux kernel documentation" finds https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/index.html

Comment: @Barmar Yes, of course I saw that. Good luck navigating it.